# How <selectKey> support multiple DataSource in MyBatis

Tags: mybatis

In Mybatis, we use `<selectedKey>` for generated column when define the `insert` statement, but for different DB it has different content in `selectedKey` element.

For MySQL like this:

```
 <selectKey resultType="java.lang.Long" order="AFTER" keyProperty="productId">
      SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()
  </selectKey>
```

For Oracle like this:

```
<selectKey resultType="java.math.BigDecimal" order="BEFORE" keyProperty="id">  
   SELECT U_USER_INFO_SEQ.Nextval as ID from DUAL  </selectKey>
```

So how this support multiple DataSource?

Answer (score 1):

You can try using http://www.mybatis.org/mybatis-3/configuration.html#databaseIdProvider.
Doing so allows you to use `_databaseId` as described http://www.mybatis.org/mybatis-3/dynamic-sql.html#Multi-db_vendor_support

Comment: I have used this to support Oracle and Sql Server respectively